# Problems adding OpenCV-Dynamic cocoapod

Tags: ios, opencv, terminal, cocoapods

I am trying to add the framework OpenCV-Dynamic to my Xcode project. I cannot install it manually as it is a dependency for another cocoapod. When I run pod install I get a huge error message.

This is the first part of it:

```
  [!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
git submodule init
git submodule update
python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios --dynamic
cp -a ./ios/opencv2.framework ./opencv2.framework

Submodule path 'opencv': checked out 'a8aff6f64330a0ab2c9d71033412af892dd9b710'

-- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain for IOS_ARCH='armv7;armv7s;arm64'
-- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
-- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain for IOS_ARCH='armv7;armv7s;arm64'
-- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Failed
```

I do not know what is going wrong. I have run `Xcode-select --install` already and installed the tools.

What could be the problem?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed instruction and install cmake?

“For the pod to build correctly, please make sure cmake is available from command line, by running cmake command. You can install it with Homebrew:

-> brew install cmake

Comment: I am pretty sure I did but I will just reinstall it to make sure. @Constantin Chernishov

Comment: It turns out that I have already installed cmake. Reinstalling it through Homebrew did not work. It still gives me the same error. Do you have any other ideas why it is returning an error? @Constantin Chernishov